# Where to put message (=data, payload) in geth transaction

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, calldata

Basic transaction in geth is

```
eth.sendTransaction({from:sender, to:receiver, value: amount})
```

if I want to put some HEX message (eg.FF) to this transaction, where do I put it?

Comment: This question will probably be closed [as a duplicate](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates) soon. If the answers from the duplicates don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and flag this for re-opening. Thanks!

Comment: I thought, that I have allready marked this as answered? If not, how can I do it?